# Searching for an item in a json file without knowing the array names

Tags: python

Okay so I have a file with json elements, let's just call it `json_file` and this file contains

```
{
  "array1": {
    "item1": ["item0", "item1"],
    "item2": ["item0", "item1"]
  },
  "array2": {
    "item3": ["item0", "item1"],
    "item4": ["item0", "item1"]
  }
}
```

I am trying to create a search function which will search for the items inside of the `arrays` but without specifying which array.
I tried doing this:

```
json_file = open("json.txt", "r")
data = json.load(json_file)

if "item1" in data:
   print("works")
else:
   print("doesn't work")
```

As you can guess, I get `doesn't work`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use dict.values() to get values without keys.

```
with open("json.txt", "r") as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
    for value in data.values():
        if "item1" in data:
            print("works")
        else:
            print("doesn't work")
        # or do you want to search in the list?
        # for val in value.values():
        #     if "item1" in data:
        #         print("works")
        #     else:
        #         print("doesn't work")
```

and, another point, you can actually use list directly in json file.

```
[
  [
    ["item0", "item1"],
    ["item0", "item1"]
  ],
  [
    ["item0", "item1"],
    ["item0", "item1"]
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

When you load a json file into an object with python you get the same structure as a `dict` object, with all the hierarchy contained in the json file as well.

You won't be able to access "item1" directly from the root of the object, because it is a child of "array1". So, in this special case you might want to do:

```py
# something before
if "item1" in data["array1"]:
# etc..
```

Also, you could convert this object to an actual dictionary, like this:

```py
data = dict(data)
```

and iterate over the items like this:

```py
for key, value in data.items():
    for item_key, array_value in data[key]:
        # now you have each array in the "array_value" variable
        # do stuff...
```